# Creating and modifying arbitrary-length arrays while plotting in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to count the number of occurrences of an event (for example, x data value equals some number) and store these occurrences in order, while plotting a file in gnuplot. Say I have the following file:

```
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
```

Now I want to count how many times I have a `1` and store that number in variable `N`. Then I want to know the positions where that happens and store that information in an array `pos`, all of this while plotting the file. The result, for the example above, should be:

```
print N
3
print pos
1 5 6
```

I know how to achieve the counting:

```
N = 0
plot "data" u ($0):($1 == 1 ? (N = N+1, $1) : $1)
print N
3
```

Then to achieve the position recording, it would be schematically something like this:

```
N = 0 ; pos = ""
plot "data" u ($0):($1 == 1 ? (N = N+1, pos = pos." ".$0, $1) : $1) # This doesn't work!
print N
3
print pos
1 5 6
```

How can this be done in gnuplot *without resorting to external bash commands*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as sometimes happens writing down the question triggers an idea for an answer. I'll leave it here in case somebody finds it useful:

```
N=0 ; pos=""
plot "data" u ($0):($1 == 1 ? (N = N+1, pos = sprintf("%s %g", pos, $0+1), $1) : $1)
print N
3
print pos
1 5 6
```

Note I had to use `$0+1` because position 1 is treated by gnuplot as zero.